# Blank screen when loading webvr scene

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I have a webvr scene as below, but when the scene is loaded, the screen is blank. Only when moving with the mouse in the scene, the scene appears.

```
<a-scene id="exp-view" style="width: 90vw; height: 90vh;" embedded>
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="endo-obj" src="test.obj"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>
    <a-entity position="33 0 -33" rotation="0 180 0" look-controls id="camera" camera="userHeight: 1.6" listener>

    <a-grid static-body></a-grid>

    <a-box color="#a00" scale="0.3 0.3 0.3" rotation="-90 180 0" dynamic-body="shape: box; mass: 0" position="-10 0 20" width="2" height="2" depth="2"></a-box>

    <a-box color="#abc" position="-35 0 0" width="0.001" height="6" depth="70"></a-box>
    <a-box color="#abc" position="35 0 0" width="0.001" height="6" depth="70"></a-box>

    <a-box color="#abc" position="0 0 -35" width="70" height="6" depth="0.001"></a-box>
    <a-box color="#abc" position="0 0 35" width="70" height="6" depth="0.001"></a-box>

    <a-light type="ambient" color="#bbb"></a-light>
    <a-light color="#ccc" position="0 30 0" distance="100" intensity="0.4" type="point"></a-light>
    <a-light color="#ccc" position="3 10 -10" distance="50" intensity="0.4" type="point"></a-light>
    <a-entity id="a" template="src: #scene1"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

This is a scene with few objects. However, it only gets visible once the user provided some input (for example drag the scene with a mouse). How can I show this scene directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close Your camera entity with the `</a-entity>` tag, and make sure Your model loads properly ( the source path is correct ).

Seems to be [working](https://jsfiddle.net/fxd9od01/).